# Custom label for activeadmin's has_many method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

How to create custom label for formtastic's has_many method? I have following code:

```
f.has_many :products_terms, label: 'Categories' do |ctg|
    ctg.input :category
    ctg.input :order_num
end
```

But the **:label** option does not work as it does with **f.input** method.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `f.has_many` is a feature of Active Admin, not Formtastic. As of [0.6.1](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/a20eb5c4dba16cef4a36de96965bba0d09d70cfe/CHANGELOG.md#enhancements-1) Active Admin has had the `:heading` option that does what you want.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. Could you give me some example? I was unable to found the documentation.

Comment: See the docs: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/v0.6.2/docs/5-forms.md#nested-resources

Comment: Nope, the heading doesn't change even though I follow exactly what the documentation says :-( Do you have any experience using this feature? Did it work?